# How to specify the namespace in index.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do I specify a namespace in my index.yaml?

```
Example:
- kind: Account
  properties:
  - name: first_name
  - name: balance
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig#Python_Index_definitions

Comment: Why do you need to have different indexes for different namespaces?

Comment: What if you have two or more kinds with the same name?  I don't really like the "Account" example but you could probably think of a scenario where it would make sense to have the same kind in two namespaces.

Comment: Yes, that's right, you usually have the exact same kind though all the namespaces, but the entities in each namespace belong to a different customer, domain or user (depending how you use them). That way data is not "mixed" but share the same model and logic

Comment: So that is the function of namespaces; how does NDB distinguish the difference between two kinds in index.yaml without knowing the namespace?  @DavidCifuentes Thanks for explaining!  I am not sure if this is a missing feature / bug.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Namespaces let you segregate data at a logical level but they share the index definitions and depending on how you implement them, they usually share the same kinds as well.